# Application suited for a TCP environment but are intended to operate in a UDP world?

Tags: tcp, udp

Everything these days has to operate in a TCP-friendly environment.  Even in area and applications that use UDP, we still see some TCP tendancies.

Is anyone aware of any applets or applications that are well-suited for a TCP environment but are intended to operate in a UDP world?

Comment: Your question is not clear!

Comment: well what i am trying to understand if there's any applications out there which are supposedly well-suited for TCP environment but have been operating in UDP world.

Comment: There is no such thing as a 'TCP environment' or a 'UDP world'. There are only networks, that support both. There is also no such thing as an application written for one that can operate in the other without change. Your question is meaningless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the need for TCP or UDP depends on the requirement of the applet or application.

If we look into benefits of TCP

1. High Reliability (Connection Oriented)
2. Low Level Error Handling and Packet Resending
3. Ordered (Sequential Transmission of Bytes)

And UDP is complete opposite of this.

For your question Peer to Peer File Sharing Applications like (Bear Share, Lime etc), since there are transferring files should ideally be running on TCP because of the above reasons. But they run in UDP because of the following reasons.

1. A File will not be downloaded from one peer but from multiple peers chunk by chunk (From multiple seeds)
2. A Connection can not be created and maintained because Peers may be turned off (Shutdown or Internet Disconnect) without knowledge.

So it is up to the requirement of the application